# I am getting HTTP:GATEWAY_TIMED_OUT from cloudhub

Tags: mule-esb, mule4, cloudhub

I am using a requestor connector in mule 4 for calling an API. That API takes 24 minutes to send back the response to requestor. So when I am running my application in cloudhub, I am getting **HTTP:GATEWAY_TIMED_OUT**, **error_code: 504**.

The response timeout I am setting in the requestor is **24 minutes** and connection idle timeout is set to **default(30000ms)**

How can we update the response timeout of cloudhub?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are making an HTTP request to a REST API implemented as an application deployed in CloudHub. You probably are using an URL that goes through CloudHub load balancer (example `https://myapp.us-e1.cloudhub.io/api/...`). [The load balancer has a fixed 5 minutes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide#load-balancing) that **can not be changed**. Note that 24 minutes is a lot of time to keep connections resources open.

Some alternatives could:

- Restructure your application to operate in an asynchronous manner. This might require significant effort.
- Skip the load balancer tier and [connect to the application worker directly](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide#overview) using its DNS name (example `https://mule-worker-myapp.us-e1.cloudhub.io:8082/api/...`). Be aware that going this way you will lose the benefits of using a load balancer.

Comment: thanks for the response, really appreciate it. I cannot skip LB as it is the client requirement. Also the API which i am calling is batch processing internally.

Comment: Unfortunately that might mean that the application is not well suited to run in a cloud environment.